# Classic ASP VBScript return PC name issue

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

EDIT - Better asked maybe I need to get the value from the VBScript variable NAME into the ASP form, any attempt to reference the variable other than print it to the screen is ignored.

this is on an intranet, only for internal use, and IE is used at the lowest security settings so the activeX runs without prompting.

I have a vbscript that when it runs returns what I am looking for - the client PC name

```
<script language="vbscript"> 
<!--

    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 

    NAME= objNetwork.computername

    document.write(NAME)

//--> 

</script>
```

When I run the following I get the server name:

```
<% 
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 

    strNAME = objNetwork.computername

    response.write("Value of strNAME variable: " & strNAME & "<br>")
%>
```

I need the actual PC name that the VBScript returns, and I need to insert that into a form.  Using the ASP I can do the fill of the form but it gives me the server name and I need the VBScript PC Client name.  I can not figure out how to get the VBScript name into the ASP form.

Comment: It is completely impossible for you to get that, except sometimes in an intranet.

Comment: It is an intranet and I can get the value I need using the VBScript - I am not able to get that value into the form from the VBScript

Answer (score 1):

You need client side VBScript:

```
<script language="vbscript"> 
<!--

Function SetComputerName
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
    NAME=objNetwork.computername
    Document.Forms("form1").Elements("computername").Value = NAME
End Function

SetComputerName()

//--> 

</script>
```

Put the form name or ID instead of "form1" and the input element name that should contain the computer name instead of "computername".

The script will work only if placed in the end of your HTML markup, or at least after the form HTML, if you want it placed above add such thing to your body tag: `<body onload="SetComputerName()">`

Answer (score 0):

Generate your HTML outside of your code block, like this. This is the correct syntax, but generally the client name is not exposed via browsers unless you use IE and some sort of Active-X control.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=strNAME%>" />
```

Comment: It is IE using activeX and its an intranet - the VBScript above returns the value I need but I can't get that value into the ASP form, I guess as its VBScript?  I did this:
'FPNAME = strName

and in the form where I want it I did:
'<input type="text" name="fastPickName" size="20" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px" value="<%=FPNAME%>">'


%>'